# ActionCable not calling #subscribe in channel only Registering connection

Tags: javascript, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I am running simple Rails app with [Smart Admin theme](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/smartadmin-responsive-webapp-WB0573SK0).
I tried a lot but cannot run Action cable on my application.

my_own_channel.rb

```
class MyOwnChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_for 'my_own_channel'
  end
  def unsubscribed; end
end
```

channel.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Channel < ActionCable::Channel::Base
  end
end
```

connection.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.email
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user
      if verified_user = env['warden'].user
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

../app/assets/javascripts/channels/my_own.js

```
App.status_monitor = App.cable.subscriptions.create("MyOwnChannel", {
  received: function(data) {
    alert('Received....');
  },
  connected: function() {
    alert('connected');
  },
  disconnected: function() {
    alert('disconnected now');
  }
});
```

../app/assets/javascripts/cable.js

```
//= require action_cable
//= require_self
//= require_tree ./channels

(function() {
  this.App || (this.App = {});

  App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer();

}).call(this);
```

After doing all this, In logs I do not see the stream.
In logs I see :

```
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-19 22:20:36 +0630
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-19 22:20:36 +0630
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[ActionCable] [abcdefghijklmn@gmail.com] Registered connection (abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)
```

And not streams connected are there.
The other issue is, I see the connect method in connection.rb being called but the subscribe method in the MyOwnChannel is not being called.
I have no clue what is missing, I also mounted the `/cable` routes in the routes.rb file.

Comment: Have you figured this out? If not, what happens if you type in `App.status_monitor` in the JS console in your browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this out.
The real problem was with [Pace.js](https://github.com/HubSpot/pace)
I simply commented it and Action cable started working. Did not figured out what the real conflict between the 2 js files is. But worked for now.

Comment: Really thanks. It helped a lot after I spent whole day to fix it.

Comment: Hi, I don't have pace but still my code `App.room.speak("as")` returning false every time.

Comment: MAKE THIS AN ANSWER AND GIVE YOURSELF A HIGH-FIVE. After spending nearly 19 hours straight I came across this.  LIFE SAVER <3

Answer (score 1):

This was also an issue for me. Removing `pace.js` will fix it, but you can also disable tracking of websockets which should also do the trick:

```
// set this before you load pace.js
window.paceOptions = {
  ajax: {
    trackWebSockets: false
  }
}
```

(See source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940069/solved-actioncable-rails-5-not-receiving-broadcast-to-subscribed-channel-from-3))

There's also an open issue on the pace project:
https://github.com/HubSpot/pace/issues/411